# DateTime in the transfer parameter of the edit method in the controller is always 01.01.0001 00:00:00 asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I a problem in the transfer parameter in the Edit Method "issue".

In Issue the CreatedDate and UpdatedDate is always {01.01.0001 00:00:00}.

The parameter Id, Title and Description is always correct.

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,Description")] Issue issue)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(issue).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(issue);
}
```

My Model:

```
public class Issue : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    
    [AllowHtml]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

}

public class BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

I can unfortunately can not debug from where the "issue" parameter comes from.

From where the transfer parameter "Issue issue" in the Edit method comes from and why are all DateTimes always {01.01.0001 00:00:00}?

When I create the first time a issue entity I add the DateTimme in the SaveChanges() Method with the following modification in my DBContext:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var entries = ChangeTracker
        .Entries()
        .Where(e => e.Entity is BaseEntity && (
                e.State == EntityState.Added
                || e.State == EntityState.Modified));

    foreach (var entityEntry in entries)
    {
        ((BaseEntity)entityEntry.Entity).UpdatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

        if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            ((BaseEntity)entityEntry.Entity).CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

And the SaveChanges() works without problem. When I create the issue entity the first time the DateTime has the correct value and I can also see it in the Detail View.

Comment: Are the CreatedDate and UpdatedDate in the form section of your view?  This is usually where this issue pops up.  You can use a hidden element to keep them on the page, or alternatively you can fetch the record again in your edit method and get the values again (this is more secure but requires an additional transaction).

Comment: Tried to fetch the record again in the edit method. But if I do it I get the following error: `Attaching an entity of type 'Issue' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values...`

Answer (score 0):

Change your edit code to this

```
var exist =  d.Set<Issue>().FindAsync(issue.Id);
 
if (exist == null)
                {
//ErrorMessage = "Can't find item to update";
                    
}
else{

    db.Entry(exist).CurrentValues.SetValues(issue);
    var result = await db.SaveChanges(); // result should be  > 0
}
```